# if $f’(x)/g’(x) = f(x)/g(x)$, what can we say about the relationship?

Tags: calculus

Suppose for all $x$,
$$f’(x)/g’(x) = f(x)/g(x),$$
Then what can we say about the relationship between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

I think the only solution is $f(x) = cg(x)$ for some non-zero constant $c$. Is there any other possible relationship?

Comment: But $c$ could be $0$: there is no reason for $f$ not to be identically $0$ (as opposed to $g$, which can't be $0$ if we want the right side to be defined and can't be constant if we want the left side to be defined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can obtain $f'/f=g'/g$ from the problem statement. Integrating both sides gives:

$$\ln(f(x))=\ln(g(x))+C_1,$$

where $C_1$ is our combined constant of integration. Exponentiating both sides gives us:

$$f(x)=cg(x),$$

where $c=e^{C_1}$.
Your idea was correct.

EDIT: I saw JohnDoe's comment after posting my answer.

EDIT 2: Of course, this all only works when none of $g, g',$ or $f$ is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Then the numerator of quotient rule for derivative of $f/g$ vanishes and so $f/g$ constant. Need to do more work on it for  proof...

Comment: Or rearrange to $f'/f=g'/g$, then integrate and exponentiate. Then $f=cg$

Comment: John-- I think that's better, avoids assumptions about derivatives... If you put as an answer I'd upvote it.

Comment: Never mind, there is already an answer to that tune :)

Comment: @JohnDoe You probably posted your comment while I was writing my answer. I don't want to steal your thunder. Would you like me to delete mine so you can post it?

Comment: @TheCount No, that's fine, keep the answer up - you also had the same idea and so posted it. I don't mind at all :)

Comment: @JohnDoe Very kind of you, thank you.